# Passing string to action attached to button in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to pass a string from a text field into a button action. The point of this code is to take a typed phrase and speak it aloud. When I run the code with static text, I get the desired outcome (I.e. the static text is read aloud). However when I try to modify my code to pass typed text along, I keep getting an error message that says '()' is not convertible to '() -> Void'. I am unsure where the error lies.

**Original code that works**

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter Text Here", text: $text)
            Text(text)
            Button(action: Speek) {
            Text("Speek")
            }
        }

    }
}

func Speek {
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "This is a test")
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    synthesizer.speak(utterance)
}
```

**Code that produces the error**

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter Text Here", text: $text)
            Text(text)
            Button(action: Speek(phrase: text)) {
            Text("Speek")
            }
        }

    }
}

func Speek (phrase: String) {
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: phrase)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    synthesizer.speak(utterance)
}
```

Comment: Did you try Button(action: { Speek(phrase: text) } ) // Note that functionalists should start with lowercase, but that's not the cause or error.

Comment: No, I didn't try that before but I did and that solved the problem.

Comment: Yay, glad you found a solution!  You or @claude31 can post that in the Answer section to let people know you got an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're *very* close. Truth is, you **don't** need to pass it - you already have it! Here's code that works:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter Text Here", text: $text)
            Text(text)
            Button(action: {
                self.speak()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName:"faceid").font(Font.body.weight(.bold))
                    Text("Speak").font(Font.body.weight(.bold))
                }.frame(width: 150)
            }
        }
    }
    func speak () {
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

        let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }
}
```

- The only relevant change I did was to remove all traces of `phrase` in your function and call and simply used `text`. I may have made a second relevant change, because the code you posted didn't make it clear that the function should be part of `ContentView`.
- I took the liberty to (a) change your function name from "Speek" to "Speak" - since you are using `en-US` I thought correct spelling would look better and (b) properly made the function name "camel-case", as that is how most Swift code is.

Finally, one last suggestion to the code I have above - move `speak` into an `ObservableObject` (basically a `class` and/or your model) and expose it as an `EnvirronmentObject`. What you accomplish there is quite a bit, including removing functional code (`speak`) from your UI.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Button(action: { Speek(phrase: text) } )
```

// Note that function name should start with lowercase

Answer (score 0):

While @dfd did have an answer, it doesn't explain why your code didn't work and why his now does.

`Button`s action takes a function. In your first case you passed it the function `Speak`. Which has a type of `() -> Void`, meaning it takes no arguments and returns no value.

In your error case you are calling the function, so the result of that function call is being passed as the argument for `action:`. And as I just mentioned, the result for the `Speak` function is `Void`.

Also it's good to know `Void` is an alias for `()`.